# fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, graphics

This is the program :

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
 MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("Hello, Windows!"), TEXT ("HelloMsg"), 0) ;

 return 0 ;
}
```

I can't understand the error.Please help in correcting it.

```
**ERROR** `fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: Which VS are you using? Do you have the Windows SDK installed? Which Windows version are you targeting?

Comment: Is that the complete error message?  This error usually includes the name of the symbol that's missing, and that would be invaluable in deciphering your error.

Comment: I am using **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express** as a compiler

Comment: @ Nocturnal I am targeting win7

Comment: @ templatetypedef Yes that is the complete error msg

Comment: Try installing the most recent Windows SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be working on a `console project` and trying to make a `windows application` !
If it is so,select a new win32 project from `file->new` and then re-write that code.
**You will have this as output:**

[image]

Comment: completely forgot about project misconfiguration!

Answer (score 1):

Add user32.lib to your link libraries list.

Martyn

Comment: Depends on how you build? If you are using Visual Studio, you will find a list of .lib files on one of the linker portions of Project Settings. If you have a makefile, you can add it to the linker command line.

Comment: @ Martyn Lovell I am unable to do this..

Comment: Why? How do you build? What version of VS? What did you do when trying to add this to the lib list, and what stops you from adding this?

Comment: I think it has already been added. I go to project->properties->linker->input->additional dependencies.It is already there.I use visual c++ 2010 express

Comment: OK. In that case, add the switch /verbose to the linker options, and attach the full build log.

Comment: where to add this (linker options ??) ?

Comment: Yes, linker options. General. Show Progress

Comment: @ Martyn Lovell
what is actually user32.lib? what does it contain ?

Comment: user32.lib contains the import references that allow your program to connect to user32.dll that contains MessageBox. It's called an import lib because it just contains enough info to allow the linker to insert a reference to the DLL in your EXE/DLL's Import Address Table (IAT).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they include the Windows SDK part of the VS Express Installation.

VS Express = stripped down version of the Commercial VS

Downloader
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en%29&id=3138

ISO
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18950

I recommend the ISO it's a good way of keeping a backup copy around.

Comment: **Windows SDK part of the VS Express Installation** what is this and what will it do ?

Comment: If he didn't have the SDK, the compile would fail, not the link.